# Jquery autocomplete, get the selected value from first textbox and populate the second textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I wanted to populate the textbox based on the selected value in the first textbox autocomplete. However not sure how to get the selected value from first textbox and query the database for the list of values to show as autocomplete values in the second text box.

My jquery code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
             minLength: 7, 
             delay: 1000,
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "autocomplete",
                dataType: "json",
                async:false,
                data: {
                    term : request.term,
                    // country_id : $("#country_id").val()
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);
                }

            });
        },
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="autocomplete-person" id="autocomplete-per" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter person name" />
  <input type="text" name="autocomplete-aadress" id="autocomplete-adrs" class="form-control" placeholder="show address of seelected name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

On the success of your ajax call, you can put a function that makes another ajax call and get the data for the second input, using the data that you have on your response.